# java.lang.RuntimeException: Schema for namespace 'http://ws.abc.com/' already contains type

Tags: java, web-services, soap, java-6

I am getting error while creating SOAP request.

```
21 May 2018 18:28:20,791 [Worker[3]] INFO  [EndpointDescriptionImpl] [1111907bbb5ef75aNTQwZDM5Y2UxNTYxYzY1Mzc2MGJlM2ViOWUxYjNjMzA.] Building AxisService from wsdl: file: /tmp/unpacked_1526941165474/META-INF/wsdl/WS11_WSDL.wsdl 21 May 2018 18:28:20,792 [Worker[3]] ERROR [WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder] [1111907bbb5ef75aNTQwZDM5Y2UxNTYxYzY1Mzc2MGJlM2ViOWUxYjNjMzA.] Schema for namespace 'http://ws.abc.com/' already contains type 'doLoginResponse java.lang.RuntimeException: Schema for namespace 'http://ws.abc.com/' already contains type 'doLoginResponse
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.addType(XmlSchema.java:311)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:158)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:347)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.getXMLSchema(WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.java:140)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.copyExtensibleElements(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:2186)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.processTypes(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:306)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.processTypes(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:297)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:265)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.buildAxisServiceFromWSDL(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:789)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.setupAxisService(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:651)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:216)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.updateEndpointDescription(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:296)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:268)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactory.java:96)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getPort(ServiceDelegate.java:233)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
        at com.alestra.ws.AddressWebService_Service.getAddressWebServicePort(AddressWebService_Service.java:51)
```

Can anyone suggest ?

Using `java 1.6` and `axis2 jars`.

I also observered that in one system same code is working fine but in other code is getting this issue. I think this is not coding issue, may be some jar or other issue but not sure.

Comment: Please, add the related code (AddressWebService_Service)

Comment: Also show the XSD for namespace `http://ws.abc.com/`.  Sounds like the schema might be invalid, containing a duplicate declaration.